# How to get values of selected dynamic checkbox input in laravel with jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel-4

**problem:** i always get a null value when i wanna return the value for the proficiency field .

**Result expected** getting the result displaying as an array for the checkboxes checked on the index page and my sql database e.g [1, 2], depending on the no of boxes selected

this is how i fetch the proficiency value from my index modal for the checkbox field input.

````
            fetch(`{{ url('fetch/proficiency/list') }}`, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            }).then(r => {
                return r.json();
            }).then(results => {
                //console.log(results);
                $("#all-proficiency").html("");
                $("#edit-all-proficiency").html("");
                $.each(results, function(index, val) {
                    $("#all-proficiency").append(`
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="proficiency[]" value="${val.id}">${val.name}<br>
                    `);
                    $("#edit-all-proficiency").append(`
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="proficiency[]" value="${val.id}">${val.name}<br>
                    `);
                });
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
        }```

**the ajax saving the project**

function saveNewProject() {
            var _token      = $('#token').val();
            var title       = $('#title').val();
            var context     = $('#context').val();
            var description = $('#description').val();
            var start_date  = $('#start_date').val();
            var project     = $('#project').val();
            var proficiency = [];
            $.each($("input[name='proficiency']:checked"), function() {
                proficiency.push($(this).val());
            });
            var details     = $('#details').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "add/project",
                type: "POST",
                data:{
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    title:title,
                    context:context,
                    description:description,
                    start_date:start_date,
                    project:project,
                    stack:stack,
                    proficiency:proficiency,
                    details:details,`


**my project model where i fetch the proficiency from...**


public function getProficiencyList(){
        // body
        $proficiency = [
            [
                "id"    => 1,
                "name"  => "Expert"
            ],
            [
                "id"    => 2,
                "name"  => "Intermediate"
            ],
            [
                "id"    => 3,
                "name"  => "Beginner"
            ],
            [ 
                "id"    => 4,
                "name"  => "Novice"
            ],
        ];


        // return
        return $proficiency;
    }
````

Comment: Wow. I just resolved it. There is a typo in my model. My code was correct.